# How to convert from "with 'argument' select" to if else statment in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

Our assignment is to design a 4-bit ALU in VHDL using Xilinx and I'm having problems in the design of the 1 bit ALU. I found an example on Internet which uses with "Argument" select statments, here is the example:

```
FullAdder: OneBitAdder port map (InputSignal(1),InputSignal(0),CarryIn, ArithmeticModeOutput(1),ArithmeticModeOutput(0));

with Mode select
    UnitOutput <= ('0' & LogicModeOutput) when '0',
                        ArithmeticModeOutput when '1',
                        "00" when others;

with Sel select
    LogicModeOutput <= (J and K) when "00",
                            (J or K) when "01",
                            ( J xor K) when "10",
                            ( J xnor K) when "11",
                            '0' when others;

with Sel select
    InputSignal <= (J & '0') when "00",
                            (J ,K) when "01",
                            ( J, not K) when "10",
                            ( not J, K) when "11",
                            "00" when others;
CarryOut <= UnitOutput(1);
Foutput <= UnitOutput(0);
```

This code works, it compiles without an error and the simulation works but our assignment wants it to be an if else statment. I tried writing one but it did not work properly:

```
process (Mode,Sel,J,K)
begin
if(Sel(1) = '0') and (Mode ='0') then --Logic mode combinations
  if(Sel(0) = '0') then
  LogicModeOutput <= (J and K);
  else
  LogicModeOutput <= (J or K);
  end if;

else

  if(Sel(0) = '0') then
  LogicModeOutput <= (J xor K);
  else
  LogicModeOutput <= (J xnor K);
  end if;


end if;
end process;

process (Mode,Sel,J,K)
begin
if(Sel = "00") then --Arithmetic mode combinations

  InputSignal <= (J & '0'); -- since J is 1-bit, we have to add a '0' after.

elsif(Sel = "01") then

  InputSignal <= (J , K); -- J and K are 1-bit, so we concatenate them.

elsif(Sel = "10") then

  InputSignal <= (J, not K);

elsif(Sel = "11") then

  InputSignal <= (not J, K);

else

  InputSignal <= "00";

end if;
end process;

process (Mode)
begin
if(Mode = '0') then --how to select the mode

  UnitOutput <= ('0' & LogicModeOutput); -- since LogicModeOutput is 1-bit, we 
have to add a '0' before.

elsif(Mode = '1') then

  UnitOutput <= ArithmeticModeOutput;

else

  UnitOutput <= "00";

end if;
end process;
```

I'm open to all suggestions with my priority being that it should be an if else statment. Thank you for your contributions.

Comment: And what have you done about it not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for the answer, I wrote something which works:

```
FullAdder: OneBitAdder port map (InputSignal(1),InputSignal(0),CarryIn, ArithmeticModeOutput(1),ArithmeticModeOutput(0));    

process (Sel,J,K, LogicModeOutput, InputSignal)

begin

if(Sel = "00") then

LogicModeOutput <= (J and K);
InputSignal <= (J & '0');
elsif(Sel = "01") then

LogicModeOutput <= (J or K);
InputSignal <= (J, K );
elsif(Sel = "10") then

LogicModeOutput <= (J xor K);
InputSignal <= (J, not K);

elsif(Sel = "11") then

LogicModeOutput <= (J xnor K);
InputSignal <= (not J, K);

else 

LogicModeOutput <= '0';
InputSignal <= "00";

end if;

end process;

process (Mode, UnitOutput, LogicModeOutput, ArithmeticModeOutput)

begin

if (Mode = '0') then

UnitOutput <= ('0' & LogicModeOutput);

elsif(Mode = '1') then

UnitOutput <= ArithmeticModeOutput;

else

UnitOutput <= "00";

end if;

end process;


--Our output signal was 2 bit, we seperate the bits for the function.
CarryOut <= UnitOutput(1);
Foutput <= UnitOutput(0);
```

Comment: In your final if-else statement, how is the statement “UnitOutput <= “00”” going to be reached? If Mode is 1-bit, it’s either 0 or 1 - there is no “else”.

Comment: I just added it in case, for an else case to exist. Should I remove the elsif and make it the else case? In addition, I'm now trying to implement signed vectors for inputs and the output, but I'm using a generic bitwise full adder. Any idea how I can do it without changing the general design?

Comment: @Blair it will suppress the warnings of "latch inferred"

Comment: @MITURAJ latches are inferred when you have if-else statements with assignments to a signal in one branch and not the other - not the case here (assuming he changes his malformed code to a simple if-else, which is what I was suggesting)

Comment: @MITURAJ in other words: not if it’s done properly.

Comment: @MITURAJ Also, if you don't understand the warning, you probably shouldn't suppress it.